# sum for loop quantity values?

Tags: android, for-loop

i have this code..

```
JSONObject jsonObjcart = new JSONObject(myJSONCartProducts);
jsonarrayCartProducts = jsonObjcart.getJSONArray("cartproducts");

cartarraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarrayCartProducts.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> lmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject p = jsonarrayCartProducts.getJSONObject(i);
    // Retrive JSON Objects
    lmap.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
    lmap.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
    lmap.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
    lmap.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
    lmap.put("customers_basket_quantity", p.getString("customers_basket_quantity"));
    lmap.put("products_price_total", p.getString("products_price_total"));
    lmap.put("pcustomersid", customersid);
    lmap.put("pcountryid", countryid);
    lmap.put("customers_basket_id", p.getString("customers_basket_id"));
    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
    cartarraylist.add(lmap);
}
```

i want to sum the quantity `p.getString("customers_basket_quantity")` and set to my textview..

i tried to do create an

```
int qtySum=0;
int qtyNum;
```

and do this inside for loop..

```
qtyNum = Integer.parseInt(p.getString("customers_basket_quantity"));
        qtySum += qtyNum;
```

and set qtySum to my textview

```
textTotalitems.setText(qtySum);
```

but i got error, the app crashed..

this is updated code with sum i tried..

```
JSONObject jsonObjcart = new JSONObject(myJSONCartProducts);
jsonarrayCartProducts = jsonObjcart.getJSONArray("cartproducts");

cartarraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
int qtySum=0;
int qtyNum;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarrayCartProducts.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> lmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject p = jsonarrayCartProducts.getJSONObject(i);
    // Retrive JSON Objects
    lmap.put("products_id", p.getString("products_id"));
    lmap.put("products_name", p.getString("products_name"));
    lmap.put("products_price", p.getString("products_price"));
    lmap.put("products_image", p.getString("products_image"));
    lmap.put("customers_basket_quantity", p.getString("customers_basket_quantity"));
    lmap.put("products_price_total", p.getString("products_price_total"));
    lmap.put("pcustomersid", customersid);
    lmap.put("pcountryid", countryid);
    lmap.put("customers_basket_id", p.getString("customers_basket_id"));
    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
    qtyNum = Integer.parseInt(p.getString("customers_basket_quantity"));
    qtySum += qtyNum;
    cartarraylist.add(lmap);
}
textTotalitems.setText(qtySum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
textTotalitems.setText(String.valueOf(qtySum));
```

instead of

```
textTotalitems.setText(qtySum);
```

With your current implementation your trying to set a resource-Id to your TextView, because TextView has an overloaded setText(int resId)-method.